# How to refer maven dependency jars from an executable jar?

Tags: java, maven, jar, manifest, pom.xml

I have an executable jar which needs to be placed in an Eclipse Maven project (Lets assume in the first folder of the project). In the manifest file of this jar, I need to refer to the maven dependency jars. How can I specify that in MANIFEST.MF file using pom.xml? Is it possible?

Comment: Your questions in not clear. Are you trying to add executable jar as dependency in another project. And also, unless it's an OSGi environment, we don't really modify manifest file.

Comment: We need to give an executable jar and a template Maven project to the client. He places the jar in the project and executes it. Now my executable jar has some dependencies. All those dependencies are mentioned in pom.xml. So I need to refer Maven dependencies when I execute the jar.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can specify jars using maven-jar-plugin.
you can specify dependent jars in manifest tag
E.g.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: This will download all the jars into dependency-jars folder, if I'm not wrong. Since Maven dependency jars are already in the classpath, I dont want to download all the jars again.

Comment: no this will not download the jar , here you can provide path to the dependency jars. Suppose you have jars in your lib folder then you can give entry as <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>

Comment: you can refer this link for more info :https://caffebig.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/executable-jar-file-with-dependent-jars-using-maven/

Comment: I don't have all these dependent jars physically in my project. There are some 40 dependent jars. I dont want to add these jars in my template project which I'm giving it to the client. I mention the dependencies in pom and it will download the jars into his local repository.

Comment: then you can use maven-copy dependency feature in your template project.
It will download the jars in some folder and your exe jar can refer those dependent jars.

Comment: Well the point is we dont want the jars to be downloaded or copied again to the project or any folders. Just like the java files will have Maven dependencies in classpath (although there is no physical jars in any folder, apart from local maven repository), I want my jar also to refer it similarly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74332/discussion-between-naveenbharadwaj-and-sachin-gupta).